# C++ Using Class to Define New Type

Tags: c++

I am working on an operating system right now.  However, I had to create the type "String" for developers.
I've tried typedefs and enumerations but they all didn't fit my need. I wanted to make the type string work like Windows's VB.Net.
Like this:

```
string a
a = "Hello, "
a.CombineString ("World")
int a = a.NumberOfChars ()
```

so I came up with this (in c++)

```
class string {
    char * value = NULL; //My Operating System's Kernel's Printf Function Uses Char Pointers
    bool CompareString (char *);
    int NumberOfChars () {return (!value);}
    void CombineString (char *);
}

bool string::CompareString(char * string_to_compare_with) {
    int return_prototype = 0;
    return_prototype = strcmp(string::value, string_to_compare_with);  //The strcmp () function returns 0 if the char*s are the same and 1 if different.
    if(return_prototype == 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

void string::CombineString(char * string_to_add) {
    value = strcpy(value, string_to_add);
}

int main() {
    string a;
    a.value = "Hello, ";
    a.CombineString("World!!");
    Printf(a);
}
```

This prints the string "Hello, World!!" on the console screen in my Operating System. **BUT** I want to just go

```
string a = "Hello, ";
```

**NOT**

```
string a;
a.value = "Hello, ";
```

What should I do?

Comment: I mean no harm, but if you're writing an OS shouldn't string handling be, like, a no-brainer?

Comment: Why not use `std::string`:  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/ ?

Comment: Could anyone please remove this question? I don't even know how I wrote a question as bad as this. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Defining a constructor that takes a `const char*` as parameter and a copy constructor should do it. Having a copy constructor there also means you'd need a copy assignment operator and a destructor. You should also decide whether your objects assume ownership of the strings. In your example - `a.value = "Hello, ";` - just makes that member point to that string literal. You won't be able to modify it afterwards - perhaps make a copy there?

However, I must point out the existing `std::string` implementation that exists in `<string>`.

Comment: This is an operating system, not an application. Just the standard libraries written from scratch are 13,486 lines long. Besides, I'm a student... (surprise)

Comment: @Arcrascent: `std::string` is defined by the C++ standard, and is not related to Windows.

Answer (score 3):

I'm Simple Fellow. I am working on an operating system called "Windows" right now.  It runs on its own filesystem, the NTFS filesystem, and supports user mode, execution of applications, memory management, and other awesome stuffs.

Besides having a copy constructor, you also need assignment operator overload:

```
 const string& operator=(const string& arg){
    delete[] value;
    value = new char[arg.NumberOfChars()+1];
    CombineString(const_cast<char*>(arg));
    return reinterpret_cast<string&>(*this);
 }

 string(const string& arg):value(NULL){
    value = new char[arg.NumberOfChars()+1];
    CombineString(arg);
    return reinterpret_cast<string&>(*this);
 }
```

Comment: For the record, the mild snark prefacing this answer was modeled after the... unnecessary intro to the question, before I just now edited it out. So don't punish this simple guy for it. Unless you want to, then be my guest!